# How can I partition a NoSQL database by location so that a central server has data for all locations, but each locations only has its data?

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a system where I need to have a local subset of data on a gateway at a location in a multi-location distributed system. I want a central server to have data for ALL locations.

I also want to keep the central data synchronized with the location copies in the case where data changes are made at the center or at the location.

Which NoSQL databases can handle this requirement? I've looked at sharding and replicating options for Mongo, and it doesn't seem to support this design.

Comment: Neil, why did you remove nosql tag?